# Calling global custom action using JavaScript in Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm having trouble calling my global custom action using JavaScript in Dynamics CRM.

[In CRM I created this global action that takes an in parameter and returns an out parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgCA4.png). I've confirmed that the action is activated and works. The problem arises when I try to call it using JavaScript.

My JavaScript code is as follows:

```
callCustomAction: function (actionName, actionParameters) {
    var result = null;

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", encodeURI(Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/" + actionName), false);
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;

            if (this.status == 200) {
                result = JSON.parse(this.response);
            } else {
                var error = JSON.parse(this.response).error;
                alert(error.message);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send(window.JSON.stringify(actionParameters));

    return result;
}
```

Now, to me this looks correct but I got an issue with the URL which at the moment leads to nowhere. Everywhere I look the URL for a global action is simply the organization URL followed by "/api/data/v8.2/" and the name of my action but for me it's not working and I can't figure out why.

**Resolved**
The issue was using a mix of EntityReferences and strings as out parameters which made my action not show up under metadata

Comment: Do you have any specific error? You are very unclear in your question what exactly is the problem. "URL leading to nowhere" is not a problem - this is a POST action so you will not get any response from GET by posting the link in your browser... What error is brought back from the server when you execute your JS?

Comment: When I do alert(this.status); I get 404 if that's what you mean. That's why I figured my URL is wrong.

Comment: And when you export your metadata (Customizations -> Developer Resources -> Download Odata Metadata) is your custom action available there and Input/Output parameters are ok? Also - are you sure this is not cut off by some cross site scripting policy, maybe you connect to your CRM via IP and call API via full domain name (I saw this error made too many times...)

Comment: Also doing alert(this.status) is not really debugging. Attach some Developer Tools debugger from whatever browser you use and check the full error message (even without debugger you should be able to see it in Networking tab of your Developer Tools)

Comment: I downloaded Odata Metadata but couldn't find my action. Could that be what's causing the issue? Don't know about cross site scripting policies.

Comment: If your custom action is not there, then for sure it will not be working. Do some tests - create some dummy action just to see if it occurs in the metadata. Don't forget to publish all customizations before you export metadata

Comment: Can you please post screenshot of your action? It looks similar to issue I described in my post - https://butenko.pro/2016/09/23/action-not-available-webapi/

Comment: I included a screenshot in my post. You can check the link in the second paragraph @AndriiButenko. It's in swedish though so you might have to do some translating

Comment: Can you please check if your Action was published using metadata url - https://yourorgname.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/$metadata

Comment: It wasn't. Checked your previous link and that was my exact issue. Changed the out parameters from a mix of EntityReferences and strings to only strings and it showed up under metadata. I'm now able to call on it using my JavaScript method. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Global actions which have an output parameter associated cant be called using the Web API. This is not the case for actions having no output parameter.

This is because sometimes the status code is 200 and sometimes different. We noticed this bug and observed it to happen only with actions having output parameter. Also we noticed this happening on certain times and not frequently as in at times you will get output but sometimes not.

As a workaround, you need to use the conventional SOAP query and execute the workflow and then parse the response.

Hope MS solves this soon

Comment: Never had this problem that you described and I use actions a lot, with or without output parameters, with complex types etc. Sometimes Actions requires to be redeployed, but once you are able to call them - they work without problem

Comment: Pawel, have you tried to add Entity/EntityReference/EntityCollection parameters along with simple parameters like string/whole number e.t.c.? Try it and your action will mystically disappear. Check this - https://butenko.pro/2016/09/23/action-not-available-webapi/